# Preventing ASP.Net JSON from dropping trailing 0 in decimal properties

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am using the built in ASP.Net `return JSON()` function to convert a View Model to JSON, in this View Model one of the properties is a `decimal`. When this property is filled with a value like `4.50` or `4.00` I have noticed that the JSON version of the View Model is dropping the trailing 0(s). How do I stop this behavior so when I read the data in the JavaScript in the View I get all the 0s?

ViewModel:

```
public class TimeCardEntryVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectCode { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public string TaskCode { get; set; }
    public string TaskDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsDurationTime { get; set; }
    public decimal HoursWorked { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    public string WorkDescription { get; set; }
}
```

ASP.Net code that returns the JSON:

```
{
    var timeEntryData = db.TimeCards
                            .Include(timeCard => timeCard.Project)
                            .Include(timeCard => timeCard.Task)
                            .Where(timeCard => timeCard.ID == timeCardID)
                            .Select(timeCard => new TimeCardEntryVM()
                            {
                                ID = timeCard.ID,
                                EndTime = timeCard.EndDateTime,
                                ProjectCode = timeCard.Project.Code,
                                ProjectDescription = timeCard.Project.Description,
                                StartTime = timeCard.StartDateTime,
                                TaskCode = timeCard.Task.Code,
                                TaskDescription = timeCard.Task.Description,
                                HoursWorked = (decimal)timeCard.TimeWorked,
                                IsDurationTime = timeCard.IsDurationTime,
                                WorkDescription = timeCard.WorkDescription
                            }).First();

    return Json(timeEntryData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

JavaScript code I am using to check the value:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/TimeCard/TimeCardEntry",
    data: { timeCardID: args.row["uid"] },
    success: function (data)
    {
        alert(data["HoursWorked"]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just format the result in JavaScript using [.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/TimeCard/TimeCardEntry",
    data: { timeCardID: args.row["uid"] },
    success: function (data)
    {
        var formattedHours = data.HoursWorked.toFixed(2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did not run across that in my searches, though did not get many decent results when it came to my searches, most of the results where about how to truncate. That worked thank you.